# Dynamically add multiple instances of the same model to ActiveForm

Tags: ajax, yii2, active-form

I have a form that uses multiple of the same model. When the user clicks "add item" it creates a new row (in this case a elements of a 'model') to ActiveForm. This is important in cases when you have a form where the amount of items needed to be added are unknown and rather than have the user navigate multiple pages I would like to use one form. I found a way to save these elements but currently my method (I'm using renderAjax()) loses its client validation for the new elements.

I would like to know if anyone has had experience in using ActiveForm and Ajaxing in new form elements from models and still retain client validation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly a cookie cutter method like some JS frameworks but this works.

Clone this attr:

```
$('#someForm').yiiActiveForm('find','id');
```

Then modify and add to ActiveForm:

```
$('#someForm').yiiActiveForm('add', cloned_attr);
```

I'm not exactly sure if I messed something up or if its intended this way but validation is working now.

Comment: I am facing same problem. Maybe you found the better solution or I should use this one?